# NextJs Typescript - the component does not update when setState called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, use-state

I have the following codes for a next page using Typescript:

```
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { useState } from "react";

const Test: NextPage = () => {
  const initList = ["a", "b", "c"];
  const [list, setList] = useState<Array<String>>(initList);
  const handleClick = () => {
      var listTemp = list;
      listTemp.push("z");
      setList(listTemp);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {list.map((item) => (
        <h1>{item}</h1>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
          Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

My expected behavior is when I click the button the `list` expands while the page gets rendered.
But apparently, the state has been changed but the component does not.

Is there any misunderstanding of mine here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state object.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  var listTemp = list; // <-- listTemp is reference to list state
  listTemp.push("z");  // <-- mutates the array
  setList(listTemp);   // <-- save same reference back into state
}
```

The issue is that a new array reference was never created, so React doesn't "see" that state was actually updated.

Create a shallow copy of the array and append new elements into the new array reference that is created.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  setList(list => [...list, "z"]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

** when you console *listTemp* nothing will happen.*

> const listTemp = list -------------> not work;
>
> const listTemp = [...list] --------> will work fine;

now listTemp have all list array value.

> const listTemp = [...list, 'z'] -------> Ans ["a", "b", "c", "z"];